# Retrieve values from TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: Screenshot]

I want to retrieve `amount.text` from TableView when I tap submit button.

I trying everything I know ,but still can not to retrieve `amount.text`

Can anyone give me suggest or solution?

Comment: Please can you provide some context? We don't know what the heck `amount.text` is or where it comes from. I'm assuming `amount` points to a `UITextField` in a cell but I don't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create one `NSDictionary`, and saved all type and their count. Make this instance variable so you can easily access it. Then based on indexPath.row you will get the each object and it;s count.

```
{
{
type = Apple
count = 0
},
{
type = Orange
count = 0

},
{
type = Lemon
count = 0

},
{
type = Pineapple
count = 0

},
{
type = Grape
count = 0

}

}
```

This form of data you will have to keep and then it will be easy to get each dictionary for each row clicked and it's  count as well. Then you can get everything you want.

Comment: Thakns I will tell